# Getting selective tag values using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I am having trouble writing a LINQ query to get certain nodes from an XML, hope someone can help with it.
Here's the XML:

```
<EmpFieldsMap>
<Field>
  <Name insert = "false">EmpNumber</Name>  
</Field>
<Field>
  <Name insert = "true">EmpName</Name>
</Field>
<Field>
  <Name insert = "true">EmpLocation</Name>
</Field>
<Field>
  <Name update = "false">EmpAddress1</Name>
</Field>
<Field>
  <Name update = "false">EmpAddress2</Name>
</Field>
<Field>
</EmpFieldsMap>
```

As you can see some of the `Name` tags have the `insert` and others have the `update` attribute.

I need to get the tags which don't have the `insert` attribute and have the `insert` as `true`.
Meaning an `InsertCollection` should have `EmpName`, `EmpLocation`, `EmpAddress1`, and `EmpAddress2`.

This code:

```
var titles = from nameTag in xml.Element("EmpFieldsMap").Elements("Field")
             let insert = nameTag.Attribute("insert") ?? new XAttribute("insert","true")
             where insert.Value == "true"
             select nameTag.Element("Name").Value;
```

gives all the five `Field` tag values ignoring the `Where` clause.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should know, that `XAttribute` can be cast to `bool` and will return correct bool value for both numeric (0/1) and text (true/false) attribute values.

I would try this:

```
titles = from nameTag in xml.Element("EmpFieldsMap").Elements("Field")
         let insert = nameTag.Element("Name").Attribute("insert")
         where insert == null || (bool)insert
         select nameTag.Element("Name").Value;
```

You're trying to get insert attribute of Field element, which is nothing all the time. You should either check `nameTag.Element("Name").Attribute("insert")` or get `Name` element at the first line.

Comment: this one gives Cannot convert type 'string' to 'bool'. Removing the cast or changing it to string give Operator '||' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'string'

Comment: OK, I see a problem. You're trying to get `insert` attribute of `Field` element, which is nothing all the time. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

try it like this

```
titles = (from nameTag in xml.Element("EmpFieldsMap").Elements("Field"))
         .Where ( el=> (el.Attribute("insert").Value.Equals("true") )  ||
                        (el.Attribute("update").Value.Equals("false") )
         Select(f => new 
            {
                Text = nameTag.Element("Name").Value
             });
```